# Difference between a table (SQL) and a collection (Mongo)?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

And what are the (dis)advantages of each?

Answer (score 3):

1) In SQL, you have to create a table and define the data types; In mongoDB, you can't create a collection, it creates itself automatically when inserting data.

2) In SQL, you must insert values as per data types; In mongoDB, you can insert values of any types.

3) In SQL, you can't create a column at insert or update time; In mongoDB, it is possible.

4) In SQL, almost nothing is case sensitive; In mongoDB, everything is case sensitive .

**EX.** In SQL, the use of "use [demo]"  and "use [DEMO]" will select the same database; In mongoDB, the use of "use demo" and "use Demo" will select two different databases.

Comment: Small correction: Case sensitivity is set when you configure the database. You can select case sensitivity or not. Moreover, when you are looking for strings (e.g. `select text from dummy_table where text = 'ABC'`) it will only return values **ABC** and it will NOT return **aBC**.

Comment: Case Sensitivity in  only syntax  in mongo db (e.g  `show Collections`  give  error   and   `show collections`  give list of collection in your database)                                                        if you write query for find  **ABC**  it  fetch all record  **ABC ,abc ,Abc**

Comment: How does this biased non-answer have the most votes? :|

Answer (score 2):

**Table(SQL) - RDBMS**

- Maintains relations between the data
- Fixed or predefined schema Data is stored in rows and columns
- Foreign Key relations are supported by DB.
- Data will not be stored if we violate any of the column data type or foreign key or primary key.
- Joins can be used effectively to query the data.
- Vertically Scalable (would be limited on the hardware, say you cannot
  keep on adding RAM into a server machine, The machine has its own
  limit of how much RAM can be increased) Storing and Retrieving is
  comparatively slower when data is huge.

**MongoDB Collection - NoSQL DB**

- No relation is maintained between the data - Dynamic Schema
- Data is stored as Document
- Dynamic schema allows to save the document of any data type or any number of parameters.
- Horizontally Scalable which is simply can be done by adding more servers - Storing and Retrieving is faster
- No explicit foreign Key support is available whereas we can design the schema by having foreign key(but remember we need to maintain the relationship).
- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) performs similar operation like LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Before you step into the examination of the differences, you should first assert for yourself what kind of data you need to store, and to what degree your data has **structure**. Table-base databases are perfect for well-structured information. Non-SQL databases (like MongoDB) are best for heterogeneous data (and hence they talk about **documents**).

So, the answer to your question is another question: How does your data look like?

I know this may not be the answer you are expecting, but it may point for you to the right path of thinking.

Comment: What? I don't want to store anything (at the moment). I just want to know the difference. i.e. why it is tables are better dealing with structure and documents otherwise.

Comment: Tabular and Object DBs are aimed for **different types of data to be stored** and hence any comparison between them without taking into account your needs appears to be meaningless in the best case, misleading in the worst case (at least to me).

Comment: And how would I know which needs each DB type meets unless I know the difference between them?

Comment: OK, ok.... Simple rule: If your data is quite structured (imagine for instance that you need to store the details of people profiles like name, gender, age, height, weight, shoes size, etc.), then tables is the direction. If you need to store information whose structure is unknown, then MongoDB (or the like) is the right direction.

Comment: @allidoiswin If you want to learn, there is a way proven over the last decades: Read the docs, play around, read the docs again, then ask questions if you do not understand.